# Django: convert ManyToManyField to ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's supposed I created two models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
    size =  models.IntegerField()


class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
    car = models.ManyToManyField(Car)
```

I added entries to both models, then I realized that each Car was only related to a unique Manufacturer. So, I should convert my ManyToManyField to a ForeignKey:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
    size =  models.IntegerField()
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

How can I do that without losing my entries? I tried to look in South documentation but I did not found this way of conversion...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is nontrivial, I think you will need three migrations:

1. Add the `ForeignKey`.
2. Convert the `ManyToMany` to `ForeignKey` (using the `forwards` method).
3. Remove the `ManyToMany`.

You could possibly merge 1 and 2 or 2 and 3 together, but I wouldn't recommend it.
Additionally, you should also implement a `backwards` method for 2.

An **example** for 2.'s `forwards` would be:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        for manufacturer in orm.Manufacturer.objects.all():
             for car in manufacturer.car.all():
                  car.manufacturer = manufacturer
                  car.save()
```

Please note that:

- There is no `backwards` method here yet.
- This needs to be tested extensively: a migration is something you should be extra careful about.
- In case a car has two manufacturers, the last one will be kept.
- This is very inefficient, we do a Query per car per manufacturer!

---

You will also need to update the code that uses those relationships in step 2. / 3.

Comment: Could you provide an example of forwards method for the Car and Manufacturer models?

Comment: mmh, I have a problem on step 1 :) How can I add the ForeignKey to Car, as Manufacturer isn't defined yet? I get a: "NameError: name 'Manufacturer' is not defined"

Comment: @gueux Use [a quoted syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey), the ORM will resolve the issue for you: `ForeignKey('Manufacturer')`.

Comment: OK, thanks, that works :-). I now have the following problem: when I try to add the ForeignKey, South asks me to provide a default... Is there a way to merge step 1 and step 2?

Comment: @gueux You could make the field non required in step 1, and only make it required in step 2 or 3. Alternatively, just set a dummy value.

Comment: Oh, sure. I thought "blank=True, null=True" was not allowed for ForeignKey. Many thanks! Just to help someone who would have the same problem: I had to modify the "related_name" of the ForeignKey and of the ManyToManyField (can be anything except "manufacturer" and "car").

Answer (score 8):

Based on the excellent answer provided by Thomas Orozco, I'd like to provide the solution for Django>=1.7 (basically the point 2 *Convert the ManyToMany to ForeignKey* is what varies in newer versions of Django). So here the code for the **second** migration:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    def migrate_m2m_to_fk(apps, schema_editor):
        Manufacturer = apps.get_model("app", "Manufacturer")
        for manufacturer in Manufacturer.objects.all():
             for car in manufacturer.car.all():
                  car.manufacturer = manufacturer
                  car.save()

    def migrate_fk_to_m2m(apps, schema_editor):
        Car = apps.get_model("app", "Car")
        for c in Car.objects.all():
            if c.manufacturer:
                c.manufacturer.car.add(c)
                c.manufacturer.save()

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(migrate_m2m_to_fk, migrate_fk_to_m2m)
    ]
```

Where "app" is the Django app where the models live. Both forward and reverse migration code is shown (as Thomas mentions, running this migrations may incur in loss of data, if more than one relationship was present beforehand, so please take care).